# Error installing Ruby on Rails 4.0.0 - error compiling atomic_reference.c

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am attempting to install Rails 4.0.0 [as per the tutorial](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/ruby-on-rails-tutorial-book?version=4.0#sec-install_rails), but am getting the following error:

```
gez@akira:~$ gem install rails --version 4.0.0 --no-ri --no-rdoc
Fetching: i18n-0.6.4.gem (100%)
Successfully installed i18n-0.6.4
Fetching: multi_json-1.7.7.gem (100%)
Successfully installed multi_json-1.7.7
Fetching: tzinfo-0.3.37.gem (100%)
Successfully installed tzinfo-0.3.37
Fetching: atomic-1.1.10.gem (100%)
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing rails:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

/home/gez/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin/ruby extconf.rb
creating Makefile

make
compiling atomic_reference.c
linking shared-object atomic_reference.so

make install
/usr/bin/install -c -m 0755 atomic_reference.so /home/gez/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@railstut_rails_4_0/gems/atomic-1.1.10/lib/home/gez/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/x86_64-linux
/usr/bin/install: cannot create regular file `/home/gez/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@railstut_rails_4_0/gems/atomic-1.1.10/lib/home/gez/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/x86_64-linux': No such file or directory
make: *** [install-so] Error 1


Gem files will remain installed in /home/gez/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@railstut_rails_4_0/gems/atomic-1.1.10 for inspection.
```

It appears that two paths have become merged, but being new to Rails / Ruby I am unsure how to proceed. All previous steps appear to have completed successfully without errors.

My system is Linux Mint x86_64 (Debian based).

Comment: do you have build-essential installed?

Comment: Yes all installed and at the latest version

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like Rails 4.0 needs RubyGems 2.0.3, so the command

```
gem update --system 2.0.3
```

should work. I've updated the [tutorial](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/ruby-on-rails-tutorial-book?version=4.0) accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

Had pretty much the same problem, posted an answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17385535/error-installing-ruby-on-rails-4-0-atomic-reference-c-error-71/17391395) on how I finaly got it to install.

Basically :

- gem update --system *(updated me to 2.0.3)*
- gem update
- gem install rails *(without the version, 4.0.0 seems to be the default now)*

Good luck

Answer (score 1):

I had this exact same problem today. I was able to fix it, but I'm not entirely sure what caused the problem initially, or even how I solved it.

What I do know is it finally worked after I updated ruby gems to the latest version, instead of getting version 2.0.0 as the tutorial suggests.

```
gem update
```

instead of

```
gem update --system 2.0.0
```

Try that and let me know if it helps.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, when I run gem update I get a similar error but this time complaining about "Error installing json" although it does appear to complete. Same problem when trying to install rails though.

Comment: My next suggestion it to install JRuby. During a quick glance of the rakefile for atomic-1.1.10, it shows that if JRuby is installed, the gem will install using a different (preferred) method. I would recommend installing it using home brew.

Answer (score 0):

if you are install ruby/rails through rvm, always run

```
rvm requirements
```

after you installed rvm, before you try install ruby and rails

Answer (score 0):

try

```
gem install rails --no-ri --no-rdoc
```

Without the version, it's going to install the latest version of rails, at this time rails 4.0.0. Why you don't have the documentation???

Also you could try [this](http://wiki.rubyonrails.org/getting-started/installation/linux%22this%22)