# Error installing Ruby on Rails 4.0 - atomic_reference.c Error 71

Tags: ruby-on-rails, railstutorial.org

I am getting an error when trying to install rails (or more specifically, atomic).

```
Building native extensions.  This could take a while... ERROR:  Error installing rails:     ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /Users/dima/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin/ruby extconf.rb creating Makefile

make compiling atomic_reference.c atomic_reference.c:50:9: warning: implicit declaration of function 'OSAtomicCompareAndSwap64' is invalid in C99 [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
    if (OSAtomicCompareAndSwap64(expect_value, new_value, &DATA_PTR(self))) {
        ^ 1 warning generated. linking shared-object atomic_reference.bundle

make install /usr/bin/install -c -m 0755 atomic_reference.bundle /Users/dima/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/atomic-1.1.10/lib/Users/dima/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/x86_64-darwin12.4.0 install: /Users/dima/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/atomic-1.1.10/lib/Users/dima/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/x86_64-darwin12.4.0: No such file or directory make: *** [install-so] Error 71


Gem files will remain installed in /Users/dima/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/atomic-1.1.10 for inspection. Results logged to /Users/dima/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/atomic-1.1.10/ext/gem_make.out
```

I'm basically just following the rails tutorial (for rails 4.0 and ruby 2.0, [seen here](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/ruby-on-rails-tutorial-book?version=4.0#code-create_gemrc)) and have kind of hit a wall here, unfortunately, unable to find much info on what's happening here.

I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17353088/error-installing-ruby-on-rails-4-0-0-error-compiling-atomic-reference-c) and followed both suggestions in the answer with the same result.

Comment: What OS are you using? Edit: I assume you are using OSX by your home directory path. Have you installed XCode and XCode Command Line Interface?

Comment: I am on OSX and I have Xcode and CLI installed.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Had the very same problem, coming from that same tutorial. Got it to work following [this post](http://railsapps.github.io/installing-rails.html). Ran a few command to compare gemsets with the post but what seem to fix the problem was

- gem update --system  (without the "2.0.0" from tutorial, updated me to 2.0.3)
- gem update
- gem install rails  (again without specifying the version)

And finally it installed properly

Comment: Still having this problem

Answer (score 0):

So, in my case what seems to be failing is that the Makefile has a INSTALL=./install and there is no ./install.  I edited the Makefile to take out the ./ and then created a local spec with

```
gem spec ../../../cache/atomic-1.1.14.gem --ruby > ../../../specifications/atomic-1.1.14.gemspec
```

subsequent

```
gem install rails
```

succeeded, but no idea if this screwed up my rails instance.