# "warning: implicit declaration of function" when installing Rails 4.0.0 on Mountain Lion (10.8.4)

Tags: ruby, macos, rvm, ruby-on-rails-4

Trying to install rails on OS X Mountain Lion (10.8.4).  I installed homebrew and rvm.  Ruby (2.0.0p247) has installed properly.  However, when I try to install rails using

```
$ gem install rails
```

I eventually get the following error:

```
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
/Users/myname/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin/ruby extconf.rb
creating Makefile
make "DESTDIR="
compiling atomic_reference.c
atomic_reference.c:50:9: warning: implicit declaration of function
      'OSAtomicCompareAndSwap64' is invalid in C99
      [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
    if (OSAtomicCompareAndSwap64(expect_value, new_value, &DATA_PTR(self))) {
        ^
1 warning generated.
linking shared-object atomic_reference.bundle
make "DESTDIR=" install
/usr/bin/install -c -m 0755 atomic_reference.bundle ./.gem.20130714-19171-3oplrw
installing default atomic_reference libraries
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (NoMethodError)
    undefined method `join' for nil:NilClass
```

I have updated all my gemsets, and tried "gem update --system" as [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17385535/error-installing-ruby-on-rails-4-0-atomic-reference-c-error-71) recommended, however, to no avail.

Also, if helpful

```
$ rvm gemset list
```

provides

```
gemsets for ruby-2.0.0-p247 (found in /Users/myname/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247)
(default)
=> global
```

*note* I did first try to install rails using rbenv, but after the installation it wouldn't recognize that I installed it. So I uninstalled rbenv and rails and am now trying to follow [this tutorial](http://railsapps.github.io/installing-rails.html) but am getting the above error.

Any suggestions?

Comment: What is the output of `$ gem -v`?

Comment: by any chance did you migrate your system from older version of osx?

Comment: the output of `$ gem - v` is `2.0.5`  Also, I did not not migrate from an older version, I'm running the stock Mountain Lion that came with my Mac Mini.

Comment: I still need help with this if anyone can help! thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like Rails 4.0 needs RubyGems 2.0.3, so the command is

```
gem update --system 2.0.3
```

then install rails by

```
gem install rails
```

Comment: my current version is 2.0.5, should I be reverting to an older version?

Comment: I did `gem update --system 2.0.3` and the `gem install rails`, then I restarted my terminal window and it worked! thanks