# Update of Ruby 2.0.0-p247 to Ruby-2.0.0-p353. Error to install Rails 4.0.0. on GNU/Linux

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, linux, rvm

I am building my Ruby enviroment using `rvm 1.23.16 (stable)` and could see that Ruby passed of `ruby 2.0.0-p247` to `ruby-2.0.0-p353`, and now if try to install Rails 4.0 `rails gem install rails -v 4.0.0` or `gem install rails -v 4.0.0 --no-rdoc --no-ri.` (for ommit the documentation of installation process, like I did learn recently) I have the following error:

```
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing rails:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /home/llarruda/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/bin/ruby extconf.rb
creating Makefile

make "DESTDIR="
compiling atomic_reference.c
linking shared-object atomic_reference.so

make "DESTDIR=" install
/usr/bin/install -c -m 0755 atomic_reference.so ./.gem.20131122-9599-8hv76z
installing default atomic_reference libraries


Gem files will remain installed in /home/llarruda/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/atomic-1.1.14 for inspection.
Results logged to /home/llarruda/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/atomic-1.1.14/ext/gem_make.out
```

The content of `~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/atomic-1.1.14/ext/gem_make.out`.

```
/home/llarruda/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/bin/ruby extconf.rb
creating Makefile

make "DESTDIR="
compiling atomic_reference.c
linking shared-object atomic_reference.so

make "DESTDIR=" install
/usr/bin/install -c -m 0755 atomic_reference.so ./.gem.20131122-9599-8hv76z
installing default atomic_reference libraries
```

See the `~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/atomic-1.1.14/ext/mkmf.log`:

```
"gcc -o conftest -I/home/llarruda/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/include/ruby-2.0.0/x86_64-linux -I/home/llarruda/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/include/ruby-2.0.0/ruby/backward -I/home/llarruda/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/include/ruby-2.0.0 -I.     -O3 -fno-fast-math -ggdb3 -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wunused-variable -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wimplicit-function-declaration  -fPIC conftest.c  -L. -L/home/llarruda/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/lib -Wl,-R/home/llarruda/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/lib -L. -fstack-protector -rdynamic -Wl,-export-dynamic     -Wl,-R -Wl,/home/llarruda/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/lib -L/home/llarruda/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/lib -lruby  -lpthread -lrt -ldl -lcrypt -lm   -lc"
checked program was:
/* begin */
1: #include "ruby.h"
2: 
3: int main(int argc, char **argv)
4: {
5:   return 0;
6: }
/* end */

"gcc -o conftest -I/home/llarruda/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/include/ruby-2.0.0/x86_64-linux -I/home/llarruda/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/include/ruby-2.0.0/ruby/backward -I/home/llarruda/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/include/ruby-2.0.0 -I.     -O3 -fno-fast-math -ggdb3 -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wunused-variable -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wimplicit-function-declaration  -fPIC conftest.c  -L. -L/home/llarruda/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/lib -Wl,-R/home/llarruda/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/lib -L. -fstack-protector -rdynamic -Wl,-export-dynamic     -Wl,-R -Wl,/home/llarruda/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/lib -L/home/llarruda/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/lib -lruby  -O3 -fno-fast-math -ggdb3 -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wunused-variable -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wimplicit-function-declaration  -fPIC -lpthread -lrt -ldl -lcrypt -lm   -lc"
checked program was:
/* begin */
1: #include "ruby.h"
2: 
3: int main() {
4:   int i = 1;
5:   __sync_bool_compare_and_swap(&i, 1, 4);
6:   return (i != 4);
7: }
/* end */

./conftest
```

I have installed the same way with all gems are that environment can need, this occurred starting from update of the Ruby version.

Comment: Can you post the contents of `/home/llarruda/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/atomic-1.1.14/ext/gem_make.out` ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17385535/error-installing-ruby-on-rails-4-0-atomic-reference-c-error-71 ?

Comment: @SteveKlabnik I already passed through that, and this content which you did send me was very useful,however in this time with the most recent update version of Ruby seems a little different. some gems  in a actual state, apparently, do not have use for integration the new version of Ruby and the Rails 4.0.0 or 4.0. 1. I will keep investigating, any results on my part or the Ruby on Rails community I send a smoke sign for you. Thanks.

Comment: @mpapis I've already put in the body question.

Comment: sorry meant to ask what is in `~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/atomic-1.1.14/ext/mkmf.log`

Comment: @mpapis Oh, sure. I did. Thanks by interesting of all.

Comment: Well, apparently, it was a problem with some gem obtained from the RVM. Understandable because as the version 2.0.0-P353 was released yesterday, there's so many requirements to integrate.Today I simply run the command, without any modification, and all occurred normally now. This time I could see all process.

Comment: it was problem in compilation, maybe it happens only on your linux and it requires running `gem install atomic` two times? try removing the gem and installing again. btw. what linux do you have?

Comment: @mpapis I Did the procedure first in Elementary Luna, after I did on Debian 7.2 and Ubuntu 12.04. Happened the same thing, but one day after all work well without need unistall anything. I tried in the same say day that ruby-2.0.0-p353 version was release, i think that some gems was passing for updates. If happen again I will use your hint.

Comment: Try: `gem update rubygems-bundler` then `gem update --system` then `gem update` then `gem install rails -V=4.0.2` ?

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
gem update --system
```

and then reinstall again...............

Comment: This is a legitimate answer, regardless whether it worked for everyone. I think Lajos was a bit too quick on the "Recommend Delete" button.