# I can't install rails correctly on mac

Tags: ruby-on-rails, macos, installation

I attempt to intsall rails on mac by error still exist

I really frustrated and want some suggestions

```
 Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
 ERROR:  Error installing rails:
 ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/bin/ruby extconf.rb
 creating Makefile

 make "DESTDIR="
 xcrun cc -I. -I. -        I/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/universal-   darwin12.0 -I. -D_XOPEN_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_C_SOURCE   -fno-common -arch i386 -arch x86_64 -g -Os -pipe -fno-common -DENABLE_DTRACE  -fno-common  -pipe -fno-common   -c atomic_reference.c
 xcrun: Error: could not stat active Xcode path '/Developer'. (No such file or     directory)
 cc -arch i386 -arch x86_64 -pipe -bundle -undefined dynamic_lookup -o    atomic_reference.bundle atomic_reference.o -L. -  L/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib -L. -arch i386 -arch x86_64     -lruby  -lpthread -ldl -lobjc  
 clang: error: no such file or directory: 'atomic_reference.o'
 make: *** [atomic_reference.bundle] Error 1


 Gem files will remain installed in /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/atomic-1.1.12 for    inspection.
 Results logged to /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/atomic-1.1.12/ext/gem_make.out
```

Comment: I think you are missing Xcode Command Line Tools.

Comment: I think I need to elaborate a bit… So first If you don't have Xcode installed yet you can download it from Mac AppStore. You can download Xcode Command Line Tools from within Xcode. Then you probably want to install your own version of Ruby. I highly recommend using [rbenv](https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv) but [RVM](https://rvm.io/) is ok too.

Comment: I already installed xcode commandline tool..

Comment: alright my bad and you are right… try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17353088/error-installing-ruby-on-rails-4-0-0-error-compiling-atomic-reference-c

Answer (score 0):

I've found the best way is with Homebrew and RVM. There's an excellent Railscast on this: http://railscasts.com/episodes/310-getting-started-with-rails